# Why is my new internal hard drive no longer visible in disk utility on my macbook pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, disk-utility, install, disk-format

I just installed a new WD Blue 750 GB 5400 RPM hard drive into my Mid 2012 MacBook Pro, 13 inch, 2.5 GHz.  I attempted to erase/format the drive, but it apparently froze while going through the process.  I allowed it to run all night, but it did not progress overnight.  I attempted to startup again, but the drive is no longer visible.  I only see Disk0 Mac OS X.

I opened the terminal and upon running `diskutil corestorage list`; the results said "No CoreStorage logical volume groups found."

What are possible solutions or troubleshooting techniques I can try?  What could cause this problem?  I appreciate any help and/or guidance.

Comment: Please add the output of `diskutil list` and `gpt -r show disk0` to your question. BTW: to get a `diskutil cs list` output, you'd have to create an LVG first.

Comment: Yep, what output do you get after running diskutil list (with the drive plugged in obviously)